# something wrong for starting process command git

Tags: android, git

When I download and use this project,There are some problems here.
At first hint Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error = 2.
When I clean the project:

```
Error:A problem occurred evaluating project ':vlc-android'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'git''
```

I think this may be related to git,But after my test,found no problem git.
here is the problem.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RHZv.png)

[git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92BxR.png)

Comment: Is this a blocker, or just an annoying error message at startup?

Comment: This is the first time I imported this vlc-android project, I tried to use the clean and rebuild project to solve the problem, but the following error occurred.